# Office 365 MS Exchange - setup delegate for all calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

It is possible to setup calendar delegate for individual user:
[image: setup calendar delegate for individual user]

Is it possible to setup calendar delegate for all users? I want to setup global delegate user, that can manage all user's calendars within organization.

I try to setup delegate user for group via "Exchange admin center". This didn't work: delegate cannot manage calendars users in that group.
[image]

Comment: whats the end goal here? Set the delegates so that using Outlook you can do or its meant for accessing other mailboxes using Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: I need to change calendar events start and end date using MS Graph API. I can give my application access to all calendars and change events. But when I change event on behalf of the application - changes display as did by oranizer. I want chages displays as "<my application> behalf of <user name>". I need some how mark that changes made by application, not directly by oranizer user.

Comment: I really doubt that, as its by design(it's designed to work that way). You may want to do similar replica scenario in Outlook (outside of Microsoft Graph) as well and you will observe the same behavior.

Comment: Being said that in case if you found anything do share here; as it will be useful to others as well :)